# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.ArrayExtensions.contains(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object)'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xtext

I have xtext language server project configured to build with maven. I want to connect the VS Code language client to the server via socket for debugging. In my `xtext.ide/pom.xml`, I have made the following change

```xml
<mainClass>org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher</mainClass>
```

and now I can run the jar file on command line

```bash
java -jar xtext.ide-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-ls.jar -port 5008 -host 0.0.0.0
0    [main] INFO  ext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher  - Started server socket at /0.0.0.0:5008
```

And in my VS Code extension.ts, I have the following

```js
 var client: LanguageClient;

    let connectionInfo = {
      port: 5008,
      host: "0.0.0.0"
    };

    let serverInfo = () => {
      // Connect to language server via socket
      let socket = net.connect(connectionInfo);
      let result: StreamInfo = {
          writer: socket,
          reader: socket
      };
      return Promise.resolve(result);
  };
```

Once I start the extension, my server crashes with the error

```bash
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.ArrayExtensions.contains(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object)'
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher.getTrace(SocketServerLauncher.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher.launch(SocketServerLauncher.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher.main(SocketServerLauncher.java:52)
```

But seems that the version of `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.ArrayExtensions` I have on my classpath is correct:

[image]

(It was introduced [here](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-lib/pull/229) which got released in `2.20`

**Edit 1:** I noticed that the version in `xtext/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` was not as expected:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib;bundle-version="2.14.0"
```

I now updated that to `2.25.0`, but the error is still the same.