# Conflict of maven dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have xtext language server project configured to build with maven. I am trying to use [SocketServerLauncher.java](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/main/org.eclipse.xtext.ide/src/org/eclipse/xtext/ide/server/SocketServerLauncher.java) to debug my server. But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.ArrayExtensions.contains(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object)'
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher.getTrace(SocketServerLauncher.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher.launch(SocketServerLauncher.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher.main(SocketServerLauncher.java:52)
```

which I tried to explain in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77052620/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-boolean-org-eclipse-xtext-xbase-lib-arrayextension) question. I realized that `contains` function was introduced in `ArrayExtensions` in version `2.20`. But the `org.eclipse.lsp4j` version I had mentioned in pom.xml was `0.9.0`, which gave the following dependency graph:

[image]

So it was using `2.19.0`. So I updated the version of `org.eclipse.lsp4j` to `0.21.0`. After which I got some `NoClassDefFoundError` related to `guava` and `xtext.xbase.lib`. So I added the following in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib</artifactId>
  <version>2.32.0</version>
</dependency>
```

which also includes `guava`. So now my dependency hierarchy looks like
[image]

But now I get a new runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/lsp4j/SemanticHighlightingParams
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher.launch(SocketServerLauncher.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher.main(SocketServerLauncher.java:52)
```

But `org/eclipse/lsp4j/SemanticHighlightingParams` was [deprecated](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.lsp4j/org.eclipse.lsp4j/0.9.0/deprecated-list.html) after `0.9.0`. So I am guessing `google-inject` is trying to load `0.9.0` version of `org.eclipse.lsp4j`, even though in my pom.xml I have specified `0.21.0`. Am I on the right track? Do I need to delete the pool and let maven download again? Or there could be another place where the conflict is coming from?

**Edit 1:** I just inspected the dependency tree with

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

And I get a conflict. In one section of the output, I get

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] +- com.example.xtext:com.example.xtext.ide:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[[1;34mINFO[m] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] |  +- org.eclipse.lsp4j:org.eclipse.lsp4j:jar:0.10.0:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] |  |  +- org.eclipse.lsp4j:org.eclipse.lsp4j.generator:jar:0.10.0:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.lib:jar:2.19.0:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] |  |  |     \- org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro:jar:2.19.0:compile
```

and in another section, I get the output:

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] com.example.xtext:com.example.xtext.ide:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[[1;34mINFO[m] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] +- org.eclipse.lsp4j:org.eclipse.lsp4j:jar:0.21.0:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] |  \- org.eclipse.lsp4j:org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc:jar:0.10.0:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] |     \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
```

**Edit 2:** I added exclusions in 2 projects which might have been including the wrong version of `org.eclipse.lsp4j` with the following:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.example.xtext</groupId>
           <artifactId>com.example.xtext.ide</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.lsp4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.lsp4j</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And this is only place where I see `org.eclipse.lsp4j` being included in the `dependency:tree`

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] com.example.xtext:com.example.xtext.ide:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[[1;34mINFO[m] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] +- org.eclipse.lsp4j:org.eclipse.lsp4j:jar:0.21.0:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] |  \- org.eclipse.lsp4j:org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc:jar:0.10.0:compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] |     \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
```

But I still get the same error. Also in the "Effective POM" tab, I see the problematic versions:

```xml
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.lsp4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.lsp4j.generator</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.lsp4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.lsp4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.lsp4j.websocket</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.lsp4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.lsp4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Where is this "Effective POM" calculated from?

**Edit 3:** Finally worked!!! I reverted `org.eclipse.lsp4j` version back to `0.9.0` and reduced the version for `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib` (no specific reason as such, was just trying whatever I could):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib</artifactId>
  <version>2.26.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And now finally I get the desired output once the VC Code client starts

```
0    [main] INFO  ext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher  - Started server socket at /0.0.0.0:5008
11962 [main] INFO  ext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher  - Starting Xtext Language Server for client /127.0.0.1:47742
12020 [main] INFO  ext.ide.server.SocketServerLauncher  - Xtext Language Server has been started.
```

Comment: Welcome to dependency hell :/ You could build exclusions for the transitive dependencies, but then you have to hope the newer versions are backwards compatible.

Comment: Maven can hold multiple versions of the same library, that is not the problem. The problem is that your pom requires directly (or transitively) multiple versions of a library. Then the classloader chooses (at random) a version. And that will not work.

Comment: How can I build exclusions when both versions are directly (at least from the dep tree looks like it) coming from `com.example.xtext.ide`?

Comment: Actual the version where `0.9.0` is included from, `com.example.xtext.ide` is a dependency on `com.example.xtext.ui`! So I need to add the exclusions in this project

Comment: Finally works now, please see edit 3.

Comment: is there a reason you are still on these quite old versions?

Comment: as I explained in the edit 1 and edit 2, I am having issues with dependencies. So after some trial and error, these versions worked and I left it at that.